# internet archive ( archive.org ) python package proxy / vpn issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, vpn, archive

From behind my vpn, http proxy: 127.0.0.1:8118, I'm just trying to get the example from the quickstart of the ia package going as from the website:

[https://archive.org/developers/tutorial-find-identifier-item.html](https://github.com/jjjake/internetarchive/tree/master/internetarchive)
https://github.com/jjjake/internetarchive/tree/master/internetarchive

Standalone, this always works fine, ( so I believe the issue is in the package and not my computer ):

```
requests.get('http://google.com', proxies={'https'=127.0.0.1:8118'})
```

//ia uses HTTPS

I've tried setting the environment variable HTTPS_PROXY:

```
HTTPS_PROXY='http://127.0.0.1:8118'
```

I'm just trying to get the first working example from the website going (from behind a vpn), very simple:

```
from internetarchive import get_item
  md = {'collection': 'test_collection', 'title': 'My New Item', 'mediatype': 'movies'}
  r = item.upload('<identifier>', files=['film.txt', 'film.mov'], metadata=md, access_key='YoUrAcCEssKey', secret_key='youRSECRETKEY')
  r[0].status_code
```

I've been digging around the ia package for places to enter the proxy variable in the requests.get(..., proxies={'http':127.0.0.1:8118' }) and running test with no luck...

I'm still having no luck here. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
session = internetarchive.ArchiveSession()
proxies = {'https': 'http://localhost:8888', 'http': 'http://localhost:8888'}
session.proxies.update(proxies)
```